# Writing a counter to a file

Tags: python

Is there a direct way to write a Counter declared as `c=Counter()` to the file. Currently I am using one pair at a time, writing them to the file. Is the a pythonic way to do it.

Comment: `pickle.write(c,"somefile")`? or something like that probably

Comment: @JoranBeasley but I already have the file object. Is there any way for that.

Comment: I think pickle actually wants a file object :P (tbh not entirely sure about being able to pickle counter since i only have 2.6)

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
file.writelines('{0}={1}\n'.format(k,v) for k,v in c.items())
```

but that's not really much better than a loop.

Answer (score 0):

A guess since I use 3.6 which does not have Counter

```
 import pickle
 c = Counter()
 f = open("some_file.txt")
 pickle.dump(c,f)
```

Comment: How exactly do you want to write to a file opened for reading? :p

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pickle.dump(c, file_obj)` if you already have the file object. Alternatively, `file_obj.write(pickle.dumps(c))`, though the first is preferred.

If you need this to be done safely, you should write this out to a temporary file, and then move it to the desired location. That way you can avoid corruption of the file if the process dies mid-write.